# STL map with memcmp comparison. How to set comparison block size at runtime?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a class `Parent` that loads configuration data from a file and creates `Child` objects in a `std::map`. The `Child` objects are mapped by a `const char*` that is defined in the configuration file. For any given `Parent`, all of the children will share the same key length. So, one `Parent`'s mapped `Child` objects may have 8-byte keys and another `Parent`'s kids may use 4-byte keys.

How is it possible, either using the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057610/stl-map-with-custom-compare-function-object), or using another method, to create a new `std::map` member object with a comparison function that depends on data only available at runtime?

Specifically, I'm trying to use `memcmp(a, b, n);` like the previously linked question shows, but I want `n` to be variable instead of fixed at 4.

If I haven't explained well enough what I'm trying to do, I'll try to put it in code. How do I write the`compareKey` so that it uses `childKeyLength` to compare the map keys:

```
class Child;
class Parent {
private:
    struct compareKey {
        bool operator()(char * const a, char * const b) {
            return memcmp(a, b, childKeyLength) < 0;
        }  
    };
    std::map<const char*, Child, compareKey> children;
    size_t childKeyLength;

public:
    Parent(size_t childKeyLength)
    : childKeyLength(childKeyLength) {};
}
```

Comment: why not to use `strcmp`?

Comment: dealing with binary data that is not necessarily null terminated.

Comment: Why use  a `char*` in the first place? Why not `std::string` or `std::vector`?

Comment: @JoshuaB. you need to have some way to indicate that a key is 4 or 8

Comment: ok, after your edit, it will work as long as its only dealing with a fixed size key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your keys are really just arbitrary binary data as your comment suggests, then perhaps what you really want is:

```
std::map<std::vector<char>, Child> children;
```

`vector` already has an `operator<` that implements a strict weak ordering, so this just works.

---

If something else owns the data, then I'd suggest wrapping the length into the type and comparing that:

```
struct Data {
    const char* p;
    size_t len;
};

struct DataComparer {
    bool operator()(Data const& lhs, Data const& rhs) const {
        int cmp = memcmp(lhs.p, rhs.p, std::min(lhs.len, rhs.len));
        return cmp < 0 || cmp == 0 && lhs.len < rhs.len;

        // or if you're feeling feisty?
        // return std::make_tuple(memcmp(lhs.p, rhs.p, std::min(lhs.len, rhs.len)), lhs.len)
        //     < std::make_tuple(0, rhs.len);
    }
};

std::map<Data, Child, DataComparer> children;
```

---

If the key length is *fixed*, then you can simply make that a member of the comparison object (instead of it just floating somewhere):

```
struct MemComparer {
    size_t length;

    bool operator()(const char* lhs, const char* rhs) const {
        return memcmp(lhs, rhs, length) < 0;
    }
};
```

And now the `map` is copyable in a reasonable way - you just have to pass the `map` constructor a `MemComparer` instance.

Comment: I thought about the wrapping method you suggest. In that case, would it be better to just overload `operator<`?

Comment: @JoshuaB. Overload `operator<` on what?

Comment: `operator<` on `Data`

Comment: @JoshuaB. Depends on who you ask. There's reasons for both. I don't have a strong view.